# How to persist Spark MLlib model in a database?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

I have a `MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel` set up and trained (in the same way as in [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/ml-classification-regression.html#multilayer-perceptron-classifier) tutorial) and now I want to persist it in order to reuse the Neural Network next time I need to classify some data. The model has `load` and `save` methods to be persisted and restored in the file. But is there a way to save (and later - to load) the model in the database? (in my case it is CassandraDB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer by myself. Not sure that this is the best solution, but it works fine for me.

`MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel` (and, as far as I can see, every model of `MLlib` package) implements `Serializable` interface. So it could be serialized/deserialized as `ByteArray`.

Let's make a table for storing the model in Cassandra DB:

```
CREATE TABLE models (
  uid TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  model BLOB,

  PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);
```

Now we can write the model to the DB:

```
def saveModel(model: MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel) = {
  val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)

  oos.writeObject(model)
  oos.flush()
  oos.close()

  sc.parallelize(Seq((model.uid, "my-neural-network-model", baos.toByteArray)))
    .saveToCassandra("mykeyspace", "models", SomeColumns("uid", "name", "model"))
}
```

and read the model back:

```
def loadModel(): MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel = {
  sc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "models").map { r =>
    val bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getBytes("model").array())
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis)

    ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel]
  }.first()
}
```